# Box-Sizing Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm using box-sizing property to align left div, right div and center div within container div. The div's are not aligning. Below is the code i have tried. I also tried using px. I am using Firefox to check.

I have also added in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/F9ds9/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 

    .container{  
        width:100%;         
    }

    #left{
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top:12px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:20%;
    }

    #right{
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top:12px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:20%;
    }


    #center{
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:12px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:60%;

    }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="left">LEFT</div>
      <div id="center">CENTER</div>
      <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.container{  
        width:100%;         
    }

    #left{
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top:12px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:20%;
    }

    #right{
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top:12px;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        width:20%;
    }


   #center {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**border-box** is not **margin-box** (which by the way does not exists :) so just remove `margin:12px;` or deal with it:)

In **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F9ds9/2/)** I just modified `margin:12px;` for the center element to `margin-top:12px;` (just like the other elements). If you need the margin that you need to do some math regarding your element's widths!

```
 _____    _____________    _____
  20%  12px    60%    12px  20%
```

even using `border-box` ends up to a sum of 100%+**24px**

Answer (score 0):

The `box-sizing:border-box` or whatever box sizing you are using the box model is

```
width + padding + border = actual visible/rendered width of an element's box,
height + padding + border = actual visible/rendered height of an element's box.
```

See this demo https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#demo
    adding excess margin to child will make this property useless

Answer (score -1):

Please Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYqk9/)

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="left">LEFT</div>
        <div id="center">CENTER</div>
        <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

There are some things which you should know

Total:100% for the container
Left and right :20%
Center :60%

so total 100% will come inside the container

and on top of that you have given border

so it will add extra 6px for the three container making it exceed more than the 100% width of container so the right section will jump down.

And for center container you have not given margin top

Please refer CSS box modelling you will understand.
and use firbug in firefox for debugging it will be easier.

Comment: *extra 6px?* where's that math come from? He's using `border-box` remember? and the center element has 12px margin... on **all** sides.

Comment: Hi, Because he has given -moz-border-box it will not affect mozilla.

Comment: If you go to chrome border 1px solid for the three container that is left and right for each section will take 6px extra. See CSS box modelling.

Comment: No, exactly cause he used `-moz-` *browser vendor prefix* **it will** affect Mozilla.

Comment: If you read the question the OP is aware of vendor prefixes and he was so kind to notify us about that. See? "*I am using Firefox to check.*" So nobody is talking about Chrome